# Check Date and Month occurrences within a timespan

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a list `dateHolder` which has DateTime data type and holds hundreds of DateTime values. The list is accumulated from the oldest to the latest value. This is a function:

```
private void CheckQuarter()
{
    int lastPoint = dateHolder.Count(); //Has dates from 4/12/2015 to 30/11/2017
    DateTime startDate = dateHolder(0); //startDate = 4/12/2015
    DateTime endDate = dateHolder(lastPoint - 1); //endDate = 30/11/2017
}
```

From the above code example, I wanted to check the occurrence of certain dates in terms of **Date and Month only** . I am not interested about the year value. The dates and month value I wanted to check are:

```
1st Jan
31st Mar
1st Apr
30th Jun
1st Jul
30th Sep
1st Oct
31st Dec
```

From the above date and month values, you may see that I am checking for quarterly values. Now, within the `startDate` and `endDate`, how do I check the occurrences of those dates I mentioned? Thanks a lot...

Comment: What does "check the occurrences" mean?

Comment: @NetMage from 'startDate' to 'endDate', I wanted to see whether the 8 dates that I mentioned occurs or not

Comment: Do you mean whether the 8 dates occur inside `dateHolder`, or whether the 8 dates occur between `startDate` and `endDate`? Do you want all eight, or do you want to know which ones?

Comment: @NetMage * dates occur between startDate and endDate

Comment: What does "* dates" mean in English?

Comment: @NetMage sorry it was a typo. I want to know which are the dates that falls between the startDate and endDate, NOT to check whether those dates occur inside dateHolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to make it happen. This is the function:

```
private void CheckQuarter()
{
    int lastPoint = dateHolder.Count();
    DateTime startDate = dateHolder(0);
    DateTime endDate = dateHolder(lastPoint - 1);
    DateTime CurrD = startDate;
    while ((CurrD <= endDate))
    {
        if ((CurrD.Month == 1 && CurrD.Day == 1))  //1st Jan
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else if ((CurrD.Month == 3 && CurrD.Day == 31))  //31st Mar
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else if ((CurrD.Month == 4 && CurrD.Day == 1))  //1st Apr
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else if ((CurrD.Month == 6 && CurrD.Day == 30))  //30th Jun
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else if ((CurrD.Month == 7 && CurrD.Day == 1))  //1st July
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else if ((CurrD.Month == 9 && CurrD.Day == 30))  //30th Sep
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else if ((CurrD.Month == 10 && CurrD.Day == 1))  //1st Oct
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else if ((CurrD.Month == 12 && CurrD.Day == 31))  //31st Dec
        {
            //Do your process
        }
        else
        {
           //Do your process
        }

        CurrD = CurrD.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

This is one way to achieve my goal. But, I believe there is a simpler way which requires less coding to do this.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ `Enumerable.Count` has [an overload that takes a predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) you could use. e.g. if you only care about the month and day:

```
var yourTargetDates = new List<DateTime>()
{
    new DateTime(1, 1, 1), // Jan 1st
    new DateTime(1, 3, 31), // March 31st
    ... // etc
};

var occurrences = dateHolder.Count(d => yourTargetDates.Any(td => td.Month == d.Month && td.Day == d.Day));
```

You might still have to cater for weirdness around certain dates and times though as is usually the case when dealing with dates and times.

Comment: I understand your point, but I believe that 'var occurrences' will return the count of 'var yourTargetDates' list. But, what if 'dateHolder' doesn't contain the date? What I need is between the timespan of 'startDate' and 'endDate', the occurrences of those dates. 'dateHolder' may not contain those values

Comment: @Hari `occurrences` will simply be the number of occurrences. If there isn't any that satisfies your predicate it will be `0`. And you can change the predicate to be any other condition you want.